# Fragment is transperent and show activity's above

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my `MainActivity` layout, I have a `TabLayout` with `ViewHolder` and I'm opening `Fragment` from the adapter in my `MainActivity`. But the `Fragment` not showing properly,

I also refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575177/fragment-is-transparent-and-shows-activity-below) but it's different, I m not able to solve my problem.

Here's `main_activity_layout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="58dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="58dp" />


            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_tab_layout_height"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
                app:tabMode="fixed" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/availibility"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Availability"
                    android:textColor="@color/tab_background_selected"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                    android:id="@+id/switchAvailible"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:theme="@style/Custom.SwitchCompat.WhiteTrack" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Home"
                    android:textColor="@color/tab_background_selected"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/searchview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="250dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle_edit"
                        android:hint="What are you hungry for?"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="#212121"
                        android:textColorHint="#aaaaaa"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/search" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_contenier"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </FrameLayout>

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:fab_colorNormal="#da3c2f"
            app:fab_colorPressed="#dc4b3f"
            app:rippleColor="#99d4d4d4"
            fab:menu_icon="@drawable/filterwhite" />

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
            android:id="@+id/material_design_android_floating_action_menu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="55"
            fab:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
            fab:menu_buttonSpacing="0dp"
            fab:menu_colorNormal="#da3c2f"
            fab:menu_colorPressed="#dc4b3f"
            fab:menu_colorRipple="#99d4d4d4"
            fab:menu_fab_size="normal"
            fab:menu_icon="@drawable/fab_add"
            fab:menu_labels_colorNormal="#333"
            fab:menu_labels_colorPressed="#444"
            fab:menu_labels_colorRipple="#66efecec"
            fab:menu_labels_cornerRadius="3dp"
            fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="none"
            fab:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_out_to_right"
            fab:menu_labels_margin="0dp"
            fab:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
            fab:menu_labels_padding="8dp"
            fab:menu_labels_position="left"
            fab:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_in_from_right"
            fab:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
            fab:menu_labels_singleLine="false"
            fab:menu_labels_textColor="#f2f1f1"
            fab:menu_labels_textSize="15sp"
            fab:menu_openDirection="up">

            <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/material_design_floating_action_menu_item2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/tiffinewhite"
                fab:fab_label="Tiffin Service"
                fab:fab_size="mini" />

            <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/material_design_floating_action_menu_item3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/dishes_white"
                fab:fab_label="Add Dishes"
                fab:fab_size="mini" />
        </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>

        <com.github.fabtransitionactivity.SheetLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            app:ft_color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:ft_container_gravity="center" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_dashboard"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_dashboard_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My `MainActivity` view before opening the `Fragment`.

[image]

And after opening the `Fragment` it looks like this:

[image]

Here's how I make the fragment transaction.

```
((MyViewHolder) holder).checkout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        FragmentManager manager = ((AppCompatActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager();
        PaymentFragment paymentFragment = new PaymentFragment();
        manager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_contenier,paymentFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

    }
});
```

So my question is how can I show my `Fragment`? Is there any other way? I can't apply `DialogFragment` here. How to show fragment as a new blank `Activity`?

Comment: Well, your XML doesn't help with autogenerated id. You should create a [mcve] to recreate your problem in a simpler code.

Comment: Add white background color to your fragment layout and it will work.

Comment: It's not working.  My whole view become white.  Only floating button is visible now