# Navigation Component is not replacing current fragment activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

So, I'm trying to navigato from one Fragment to another, I have used this line

```
val action = MapsFragmentDirections.nextAction(marker?.title!!)
            findNavController().navigate(action)
```

this navigation goes to another Fragment, But in the time it reachs that fragment, I see the activity below my fragment and my fragment is transparent with the recyclerview above.

I have researched and found that I need to se replace with FragmentTransaction, but I think that is done in the background of Navigation Component.

The problem is that when inflating my other fragment, I can see my activity below the view of the fragment.

A temporary fix is to put the background of the RecyclerView as blank, but  I dont want to fix it that way, I want it to be inflated like a normal fragment without seeing nothing under it

My problem is exactly this one : [Fragment is transparent and shows Activity below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575177/fragment-is-transparent-and-shows-activity-below)

But I need to solve it with Navigation Component, and I dont see any method that helps me do that.

Or does I need to set all my view inside a fragment> tag in my xml ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any animations (i.e., `enterAnim`) attached to your action? Any kind of fade will make your Fragment semi-transparent so you'll be able to see your activity's background color underneath it

Comment: Hi Ian, yes, I have the default animations (nav_default_enter , nav_default_exit, nav_default_pop)

Comment: If I dont put the animations it also looks transparent above the activity, since the component is new, should I think to move to do it with FragmentTransactions or the problem is at my end ?

Comment: This is my flow, I have the main activity that holds all the fragments, with FragmentTransaction I inflate the first fragment ( Fragment A) and that Fragment A launches Fragment B, but Fragment B looks transparent above Fragment A

Comment: NavController only allows one Fragment at a time and does all the Fragment transactions for you. You shouldn't be doing any other transactions.

Comment: So I cant use 1 activity that hosts lets say 4 fragments ? Because I cant navigate through them

Comment: As long as you have only one at a time, a single NavHostFragment and having NavController swap between Fragments is exactly what you should be doing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196828/discussion-between-coffeebreak-and-ianhanniballake).

Comment: I have exactly how you mentioned, one NavHostFragment and then I navigate with NavController from each fragment, it navigates, but it does put my background transparent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `NavController`, you shouldn't be doing any separate `FragmentTransactions` at all - as long as you've added a `NavHostFragment` to your XML and are using the `app:navGraph` attribute to specify your graph, the `NavController` does all the work on switching between Fragments and making sure they don't overlap.