# Fragment is transparent and shows Activity below(changing to dark mode or light mode)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575177/fragment-is-transparent-and-shows-activity-below) is similar and in the answer is to change the view background to black or white, but what if user change to dark mode from light mode or light mode to dark mode from notification then the view is the still the same color, so how i fix this, it's is issue in fragment inside fragment(have transparent background) also knowns as  child fragment, i do this by

```
childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(editProfileRelativeLayout.id, EditProfileFragment(), "edit_profile_fragment").commit()
```

inside my already define fragment(parent fragment)

Answer (score 0):

you can observe theme changer inside fragment here is the code:

```
AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { nightMode ->
    val newBackgroundColor = requireContext().getColor(
        if (nightMode == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES) R.color.background_dark else R.color.background_light
    )
    view.setBackgroundColor(newBackgroundColor)
})
```

Don't need to add or replace fragment.Make sure you observe this with fragment lifecycle